# Does artificial sweetener consumption by women reduce IVF effectiveness?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, aspartame

A recent news story in the media picked up a meme that seems to be already common in "natural food" circles.

> #### Diet fizzy drinks ‘could slash chances of getting pregnant during IVF’
>
> The study concluded: “Patients should be advised about the adverse effect of sugar and mainly artificial sweeteners on the success of assisted reproduction.”

--[The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/living/1989207/diet-fizzy-drinks-could-slash-chances-of-getting-pregnant-during-ivf/)

Similar allegations have been made in the past by natural food enthusiasts. For example, [Natural Fertility Info](http://natural-fertility-info.com/aspartame.html):

> [aspartame] has been linked to infertility and birth defects through DNA damage and endocrine disruption, which leads to hormonal imbalance.

While we addressed and debunked such claims before, for example in [Does the artificial sweetener aspartame cause cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/369/does-the-artificial-sweetener-aspartame-cause-cancer) and [Does aspartame "eat" holes in your cellular membranes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15543/does-aspartame-eat-holes-in-your-cellular-membranes?s=4|1.2474), this news story seems to be based on a recent Brazilian study.

Are the results of the study represented fairly? Is the study reputable (e.g. peer reviewed, published in a reputable journal, etc.)?

Here is the study at the *American Society for Reproductive Medicine conference in Salt Lake City, Utah* [that's taking place right now](http://scientific.asrmcongress.org/Program/FullSchedule.aspx): It's in the [Scientific Congress Supplement: Oral and Poster Session Abstracts](http://scientific.asrmcongress.org/Portals/1/2016PDFs/2016AbstractSupplement.pdf?ver=2016-09-09-093055-120) at section P-420.

Comment: I've changed your claim source to the Sun because the Times was paywalled and I could not copy/paste the actual quote. I've also sligthly reworded the question to eliminate leading phrasing and make it more neutral.

Comment: @Sklivvz Damn paywalls! Also I wouldn't restrict it to aspartame (the recent study covered all sweetness not just aspartame). Otherwise no problem with revisions, though I (perhaps foolishly) trust the times more than the sun.

Comment: I located the source and edited it in. You could have done that too. The question text can now be reduced IMO.